# Difference between uploading PFFile and PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Somebody could explain me what happens when I upload something to Parse like this:

```
PFFile *imgFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Img.jpg" data:imgData];

    [imgFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            } else {

            } 
    }];
```

If I use this solution where will be the uploaded file? In which class? How can I retrieve it? I'm a bit confused, because I'm using another solution in my projects, but this version would be better because `PFFile` can be saved with `progressBlock`.

This is the other way that I'm using, in this case it's obvious the class where I upload it.

```
 PFFile *imgFileObject = [PFFile fileWithData:imgData];
 PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ImgClass"];
 photo[@"image"] = imgFileObject;
 [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                if (!succeeded) {  
                 ...
                } else {
                 ...
                }
            } 
            }];
```

What's the difference between the two solution in practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. case is using parse as a remote data storage.. kinda like treating parse as your iCloud drive or drobpox. you save a FILE
2. case is using parse as a remote database.. you don't save a FILE but make a new 'row' in the database (think of it as iCloud KV Store)

=> so PFFile uploaded as remote file (not a db entry thus it has no class)

=> PFObject is a database entry (that can then link to files or even contain data itself)

Comment: So the name of the PFFile's should be unique? As an instance, I create a unique named PFFile xy.png, upload it and then I can assign it to a PFObject by its file name?